# Fitting distribution in R with bimodally distributed data from bimodal dataset (with repeated measures)

Tags: distributions, repeated-measures, nonparametric, nested-data, lme4-nlme

I am having problems analysing a data set from a study with unbalanced design and that contains repeated measures...I inherited the data and I'm a bit lost.

The response variable is core body temperature, and the other variables are study, time of day (hh:mm), shade temperature, sun-exposed temperature and body mass.

The data comes from three trials: two performed in the same site, on same individuals (T1=5; individuals: a,b,c,d,e, T2=3; individuals: a,b,c), and one in another site (T3=4; individuals f,g,h,i); the sites have different environmental temperature ranges. Temperature data was taken every 15mins for a period of 5-10 days (i.e. repeated measures on each individual; three individuals of T2 are the same as three on T1).

The question is: does mass has an effect on body temperature regulation (mass range: 14-180kg); what is the effect of each factor?

This is what my data looks like:

[image: data visualization]

This is the lmer model (and where I'm lost) I fitted to determine the effects:

Tb ~ study + time + shade temp + sun temp + mass + (1|individualID:study)

In the random factor, what I tried to do was to account for individual variation/repeated measures, and the repeated measures of the same individuals in T1 and T2...

I also read about circular stats, but I've never used them.

Help(!)

Comment: You haven't labelled what variable your plot shows the density of.

Comment: Hi jwimberley, the variable is core body temperature of the individuals.